# find intersection between multilinestring and polygons sf r

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, r-sf

I have a set of spatial coordinates on a map, and a multilinestring that goes through them. I need to figure out the length that the line spends inside each color of polygon.

caveats:

- my minimal reprex is not very good, my actual data is a data.frame with a column for color (which is group in the real data), and some identifying columns, and a column of multipolygon geometry. I don't really know how to fabricate that, so my reprex just has 3 individual polygons.
- sometimes polygons of 2 colors overlap, in which case I hope to distinguish the length the line intersects the overlapped shapes from when the line intersects only one shape.

minimal reprex:

```
poly1 <-
  # create list of matrices and the first point same as last point
  list(
    matrix(
      c(0, 0, 
        4, 0, 
        5, 1, 
        4, 2, 
        3, 2,  
        1, 1,
        0, 0),
      ncol=2, byrow=T
    )
  ) 
poly1 <-  sf::st_polygon(poly1)


poly2 <-
  # create list of matrices and the first point same as last point
  list(
    matrix(
      c(4, 1, 
        7, 0, 
        7, 1, 
        6, 3, 
        3, 2,  
        2, 1,
        4, 1),
      ncol=2, byrow=T
    )
  ) 
poly2 <-  sf::st_polygon(poly2)


poly3 <-
  # create list of matrices and the first point same as last point
  list(
    matrix(
      c(7, 1, 
        10, 1, 
        12, 2, 
        11, 4, 
        8, 3,  
        7, 2,
        7, 1),
      ncol=2, byrow=T
    )
  ) 
poly3 <-  sf::st_polygon(poly3)



line <-   
  # create list of matrices and the first point same as last point
  list(
    matrix(
      c(0, 1, 
        2, 0, 
        4, 1, 
        6, 3, 
        8, 2,  
        10, 1,
        12, 1),
      ncol=2, byrow=T
    )
  ) 

line <-  
  sf::st_multilinestring(line)


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = poly1, fill = "green",alpha=.5) +
  geom_sf(data = poly2, fill = "blue",alpha=.5) +
  geom_sf(data = poly3, fill = "green", alpha=.5)+
  geom_sf(data = line, color="black", size=2) +
  ggthemes::theme_map()
```

desired output:

- visual representation of the st polygons cropped only to the line (I was using st_intersection()), like so:

```
poly1_cropped <- st_intersection( line, poly1)
poly2_cropped <- st_intersection( line, poly2)
poly3_cropped <- st_intersection( line, poly3)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = poly1, fill = "green",alpha=.5) +
  geom_sf(data = poly2, fill = "blue",alpha=.5) +
  geom_sf(data = poly3, fill = "green", alpha=.5)+
  geom_sf(data = line, color="black", size=2) +
  ggthemes::theme_map() +
  geom_sf(data = poly1_cropped, color="green", size=2) +
  geom_sf(data = poly2_cropped, color="blue", size=2) +
  geom_sf(data = poly3_cropped, color="green", size=2)
```

then a data frame quantifying when line goes through each shape, something like:

```
shape |  color   |   shapes_overlapping |  length   
poly1    green             0               3
poly1    green             1               .5
poly2    blue              1               .5
poly2    blue              0               2
poly3    green             0               2.5
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280760/intersecting-lines-and-polygons-and-calculating-line-length-in-r https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315447/calculate-the-percentage-of-a-line-passing-through-polygons

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which works for your example, which you can hopefully modify for your real data.

First thing I did was combine all 3 `POLYGON` objects into a `Simple feature collection`, initially with a single `MULTIPOLYGON` but then split into each separate `POLYGON` using `st_cast()`.

```
# combine polygons into a single simple feature collection
c(poly1, poly2, poly3) %>% 
  # make into simple feature
  st_sfc %>% 
  st_sf %>% 
  # split into individual polygons
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>% 
  {. ->> int1}

int1

# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 0 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 12 ymax: 4
# CRS:           NA
#                         geometry
# 1 POLYGON ((0 0, 4 0, 5 1, 4 ...
# 2 POLYGON ((4 1, 7 0, 7 1, 6 ...
# 3 POLYGON ((7 1, 10 1, 12 2, ...
```

Next, find if any of the polygons overlap and if so, how many layers are there at each overlap. We use `st_intersection()` here, but unlike your example where you find the intersection between 2 geometries, we apply it to a single `sf` object, which returns it's self-intersection, including `n.overlaps` (number of layers) and `origins` (original polygons in the overlap area). More details can be found at the `sf` page [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_ops.html). We also make a new `id` column which is unique to each polygon and number of layers.

```
# now, we need to find if any polygons overlap, and how many layers there are
int1 %>% 
  st_intersection %>% 
  filter(
    st_geometry_type(.) == 'POLYGON'
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    id = row_number()
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> int2}

int2

# Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 12 ymax: 4
# CRS:           NA
#     n.overlaps origins                       geometry id
# 1            1       1 POLYGON ((4 0, 0 0, 1 1, 3 ...  1
# 1.1          2    1, 2 POLYGON ((4 2, 5 1, 4.75 0....  2
# 2            1       2 POLYGON ((7 1, 7 0, 4.75 0....  3
# 3            1       3 POLYGON ((7 2, 8 3, 11 4, 1...  4
```

To demonstrate this, we can plot `int2` and colour (`fill`) each polygon by our `id` column.

```
int2_plot <- int2 %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(aes(fill = factor(id)))+
  geom_sf(data = line)

int2_plot
```

[image]

Then, we use `ggplot2::ggplot_build()` to pull out the components of the plot - specifically the colours corresponding to each polygon `id`. We use `plotrix::color.id()` to convert hexadecimal colour codes to colour names. This may or may not be required depending on how you will interpret the colours.

```
# now, get colours of each polygon from ggplot
int2_plot %>% 
  ggplot_build %>% 
  .$data %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
  tibble %>% 
  select(fill, group, id = group) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(
    colour = plotrix::color.id(fill), 
  ) %>% 
  select(id, colour) %>% 
  {. ->> plot_colours}

plot_colours

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
# # Rowwise: 
#      id colour       
#   <int> <chr>        
# 1     1 salmon       
# 2     2 chartreuse3  
# 3     3 turquoise3   
# 4     4 mediumpurple1
```

Now we find the length of `line` intersecting each polygon. We use `st_intersection()` to find the `LINESTRING` object which overlaps the polygon, and then `st_length()` to calculate its length. Because this example data has no `CRS`, this length is unitless and returned as a `numeric` vector. If your data has a `CRS`, `st_length()` will return a `units` vector which has a number and distance units such as `3.726 [m]`; the number can be retrieved using `as.numeric()`.

```
# now, what's the length of line intersecting each polygon (colour)?
int2 %>% 
  mutate(
    line_overlap = st_intersection(int2, line) %>% st_length
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> int3}

int3

# Simple feature collection with 4 features and 4 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 12 ymax: 4
# CRS:           NA
#     n.overlaps origins                       geometry id line_overlap
# 1            1       1 POLYGON ((4 0, 0 0, 1 1, 3 ...  1    3.7267800
# 1.1          2    1, 2 POLYGON ((4 2, 5 1, 4.75 0....  2    0.7071068
# 2            1       2 POLYGON ((7 1, 7 0, 4.75 0....  3    2.1213203
# 3            1       3 POLYGON ((7 2, 8 3, 11 4, 1...  4    2.9814240
```

Currently we have one row for the overlap areas, with a vector of the polygons involved in the overlap (`origins`). To make a separate row for each of these polygons, we convert `origins` to a `list`, which can then be split into separate rows for each list element (original polygons) using `unnest()`.

```
# now, duplicate rows where n.overlaps > 1 - so there's a row for each polygon in the overlap
int3 %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(
    origins = list(origins)
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c('origins')) %>% 
  {. ->> int4}

int4

# Simple feature collection with 5 features and 4 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 12 ymax: 4
# CRS:           NA
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#   n.overlaps origins                                         geometry    id line_overlap
#        <int>   <int>                                        <POLYGON> <int>        <dbl>
# 1          1       1 ((4 0, 0 0, 1 1, 3 2, 2 1, 4 1, 4.75 0.75, 4 0))     1        3.73 
# 2          2       1      ((4 2, 5 1, 4.75 0.75, 4 1, 2 1, 3 2, 4 2))     2        0.707
# 3          2       2      ((4 2, 5 1, 4.75 0.75, 4 1, 2 1, 3 2, 4 2))     2        0.707
# 4          1       2 ((7 1, 7 0, 4.75 0.75, 5 1, 4 2, 3 2, 6 3, 7 1))     3        2.12 
# 5          1       3         ((7 2, 8 3, 11 4, 12 2, 10 1, 7 1, 7 2))     4        2.98
```

Finally, we join in the colours of each polygon that we pulled out earlier.

```
# now, join in the colours of each polygon
int4 %>% 
  left_join(plot_colours) %>% 
  {. ->> int5}

int5

# Simple feature collection with 5 features and 5 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 12 ymax: 4
# CRS:           NA
# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#   n.overlaps origins                                         geometry    id line_overlap colour       
#        <int>   <int>                                        <POLYGON> <int>        <dbl> <chr>        
# 1          1       1 ((4 0, 0 0, 1 1, 3 2, 2 1, 4 1, 4.75 0.75, 4 0))     1        3.73  salmon       
# 2          2       1      ((4 2, 5 1, 4.75 0.75, 4 1, 2 1, 3 2, 4 2))     2        0.707 chartreuse3  
# 3          2       2      ((4 2, 5 1, 4.75 0.75, 4 1, 2 1, 3 2, 4 2))     2        0.707 chartreuse3  
# 4          1       2 ((7 1, 7 0, 4.75 0.75, 5 1, 4 2, 3 2, 6 3, 7 1))     3        2.12  turquoise3   
# 5          1       3         ((7 2, 8 3, 11 4, 12 2, 10 1, 7 1, 7 2))     4        2.98  mediumpurple1
```

If you don't want the result as an `sf` object, we can use `st_drop_geometry()` to return just the attribute components.

```
# keep the attribute data only
int5 %>% 
  st_drop_geometry

# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#   n.overlaps origins    id line_overlap colour       
# *      <int>   <int> <int>        <dbl> <chr>        
# 1          1       1     1        3.73  salmon       
# 2          2       1     2        0.707 chartreuse3  
# 3          2       2     2        0.707 chartreuse3  
# 4          1       2     3        2.12  turquoise3   
# 5          1       3     4        2.98  mediumpurple1
```