# Find intersection of multiple polygons by group

Tags: r, dplyr, intersection, r-sf

So finding the union of a more than two polygons turns out to be straight forward using st_union and group_by() from dplyr. Finding the intersection with st_intersection turns out to not be as simple since st_intersection does only work for finding intersection of two objects. What's the best way to find the intersection of multiple polygons by group?
Here's some example data

```
s1 <- rbind(c(1, 1), c(10, 1), c(10, 10), c(1, 10), c(1, 1))
s2 <- s1 + 4
s3 <- s1 - 4

group <- c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3))

df <- data.frame("group" = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)))

df <- data.frame(cbind(df, rep((c(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(s1))), st_sfc(st_polygon(list(s2))), st_sfc(st_polygon(list(s3))))), 2)))
```

What I want is to replace the geometry column with the intersection in each group, that is the object created by

```
p <- list(s1 = s1, s2 = s2, s3 = s3)

p  <-  lapply(p, function(x) st_sfc(st_polygon(list(x))))

intersection <- accumulate(p, st_intersection)$s3

intersection <- st_sfc(st_polygon(intersection))
```

So the final data would look like

```
df <- data.frame("group" = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)))

df <- data.frame(st_sf(cbind(df, rep(st_sfc(st_polygon(intersection)), 6))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it with a loop but would prefer a dplyr solution

```
agg <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, 0, 2))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  group <- df$group[i]
  vec <- df$geometry[df$group == group]
  my.list <- as.list(vec)
  output <- Reduce(st_intersection, my.list) %>% st_geometry()
  my.df <- data.frame("group" = group)
  res <- as.data.frame(st_sf(cbind(my.df, output)))
  
  agg <- rbind(agg, res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First up, `st_intersection()` can work with only a single R object, for example if you supply it with an `sf collection` it will return it's self-intersection; check out the sf page [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_ops.html) for more details, and another answer as an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69293465/13478749). The resulting `collection` includes `features` with attributes including `n.overlaps` (number of layers) and `origins` (which polygons contribute to each overlapping area).

So for this example, we employ `st_intersection()` and keep only the geometries where `n.overlaps == 3` (as there are 3 geometries in each group). Basically the steps are: make `df` into an `sf collection`, then we use `split()` to split the `sf collection` by `group`, find the self-intersection of each group, join both groups back together, then keep only the areas with 3 overlaps.

```
# example data from question ~~~~~

library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

s1 <- rbind(c(1, 1), c(10, 1), c(10, 10), c(1, 10), c(1, 1))
s2 <- s1 + 4
s3 <- s1 - 4

group <- c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3))
df <- data.frame("group" = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)))
df <- data.frame(cbind(df, rep((c(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(s1))), st_sfc(st_polygon(list(s2))), st_sfc(st_polygon(list(s3))))), 2)))


# solution ~~~~~

df %>%
  st_as_sf %>% 
  split(., .$group) %>% 
  map(st_intersection) %>% 
  bind_rows %>% 
  filter(
    n.overlaps == 3
  )

# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 3 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 5 ymin: 5 xmax: 6 ymax: 6
# CRS:           NA
#     group n.overlaps origins                       geometry
# 1.3     1          3 1, 2, 3 POLYGON ((5 5, 5 6, 6 6, 6 ...
# 4.3     2          3 1, 2, 3 POLYGON ((5 5, 5 6, 6 6, 6 ...
```

Unfortunately, this method isn't entirely `dplyr` as it uses `split()` and `map()` to iterate through each `group`, however it is pipe-able. I thought `group_by()` might have worked in place of `split() %>% map() %>% bind_rows()`, but unfortunately I couldn't get `st_intersection()` to respect `group_by()`.

Hopefully this is still useful, and perhaps someone can find a way to swap out `split()` and `map()` for `group_by()`.